# Setting a conditional breakpoint in Firebug for Mac

Tags: firefox, firebug, conditional-breakpoint

I can't seem to set a conditional breakpoint in Firebug. Every Google search I've done indicates that I should be able to Right-click the line of code in question, at which point a "bubble" will appear asking me for the condition on which the break should be executed. Right clicking does in fact toggle the breakpoint's existence, but no bubble appears. How/where do I enter my condition?

Of course Mac mouses don't have a "right-click" button but assumed I could simulate right-click using Control. I've also tried Alt and Command to no avail.

I am running on Mac/Yosemite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise you need to right-click the breakpoint column or right-click inside the line and then choose *Edit Breakpoint Condition...* from the context menu. If you do so the condition editor should appear, which looks like this on Windows (on Mac it's black):

[image: Script panel breakpoint condition editor]

There is currently (Firebug 2.0.x) no [keyboard shortcut](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts) for this action, so right-clicking is not working for you, it might be a bug in Firebug. In that case you should go through the [steps described at Firebug's first aid page](http://getfirebug.com/firstaid#To_understand_the_problem_so_it_can_be_fixed) and [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry) if the steps don't help you.

Comment: Clicking the breakpoint column no longer works but your suggestion to right-click *inside* of the column was helpful. This action causes a context menu to appear, at which point I'm able to click "Edit Breakpoint Condition." Thanks.